# Skipping validation before form submission react-hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

My form Submission would skip showing validation error message when submitting wrong input. How can I prevent submission when error message is present?

my code:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const App = () => {
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({ name: "" });
  const [formError, setFormError] = useState({});
  const [isSubmit, setIsSubmit] = useState(false);
  const [formSubmitted, setFormSubmitted] = useState(false);

  const validate = () => {
    const errors = {};
    console.log("2. errors: ", errors); //<=== point 2.
    if (formData.name.length === 0) {
      errors.name = "name required";
    }
    console.log("3. errors: ", errors);  //<=== point 3.
    return errors;
  };

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setIsSubmit(true);
    console.log("1. formData: ", formData);  //<=== point 1.
    setFormError(validate(formData));
    console.log("4. formError: ", formError);  //<=== point 4.

    // This is true only if formError is empty object
    if (
      Object.keys(formError).length === 0 &&
      formError.constructor === Object
    ) {
      console.log("5. sending data: ", formData.name);  //<=== point 5.
      // Sending data to API here
      setIsSubmit(false);
      setFormSubmitted(true);
      return;
    }

    setIsSubmit(false);
    return;
  };

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    setFormData({ ...formData, [name]: value });
  };

  return (
    <>
      {formSubmitted ? (
        <p>Thank you</p> //<=== Thank you prhase
      ) : (
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <label htmlFor="name">Your name:</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            name="name"
            value={formData.name}
            onChange={handleChange}
          />
          {formError.name && <p>{formError.name}</p>}
          {isSubmit ? (
            <p>Sending...</p>
          ) : (
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
          )}
        </form>
      )}
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

console when submitting empty input (wrong input):

```
1. formData:  {name: ''}
2. errors:  {}
3. errors:  {name: 'name required'}
4. formError:  {}
5. sending data:
```

console when submitting with input "test" (right input):

```
1. formData:  {name: 'test'}
2. errors:  {}
3. errors:  {}
4. formError:  {}
5. sending data:  test
```

When I submit a right input, the form would act as I wanted.

> submit right input -> input validation -> no error found -> send data -> show "Thank you" phrase

But if I submit wrong input.

> submit wrong input -> input validation -> error found -> append error message -> but still return empty object (to formError) -> send empty input -> show "Thank you" phrase

The problem is at point 4, the `validate()` function wont return the error message. On my actual file with API, while submitting wrong input it will show the error message (e.g. `formError.name`) (takes 1 to 2 seconds to send data to CMS) but the submission will still goes thru and show "thank you" phrase. How can I fix this? Thank you.

Comment: The thing is, `setState` will not immediately update your states value since it is async, so the value will not be changed right after calling it (in your case, you are calling `setFormError` and accessing its value right after)

Comment: That's what I'm looking after. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

State update doesn't happen synchronously.

You can extract the error in a variable (named `errors` in the example below) and do the conditional logic based on that instead of the state.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const App = () => {
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({ name: "" });
  const [formError, setFormError] = useState({});
  const [isSubmit, setIsSubmit] = useState(false);
  const [formSubmitted, setFormSubmitted] = useState(false);

  const validate = () => {
    const errors = {};
    if (formData.name.length === 0) {
      errors.name = "name required";
    }
    return errors;
  };

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setIsSubmit(true);
    const errors = validate(formData); // extracting here
    setFormError(errors); // setting state using the extracted value

    // validating using the extracted value
    if (Object.keys(errors).length === 0 && errors.constructor === Object) {
      // Sending data to API here
      setIsSubmit(false);
      setFormSubmitted(true);
      return;
    }

    setIsSubmit(false);
    return;
  };

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    setFormData({ ...formData, [name]: value });
  };

  return (
    <>
      {formSubmitted ? (
        <p>Thank you</p> //<=== Thank you prhase
      ) : (
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <label htmlFor="name">Your name:</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            name="name"
            value={formData.name}
            onChange={handleChange}
          />
          {formError.name && <p>{formError.name}</p>}
          {isSubmit ? (
            <p>Sending...</p>
          ) : (
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
          )}
        </form>
      )}
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: I see, so I have to extract the errors to new variable because useState wont update immediately. Thanks works like charm

Comment: @satudaku Consider upvoting & accepting this as an answer if your problem is resolved.

Comment: actually the variable `errors` wont get changed. Making same error message stuck for next render. Any solution for that?

Comment: @satudaku I didn't get that variable `errors` will change everytime the submit handler is called can you share your code in codesandbox - I'll help you with that.

Comment: Sorry, I left out changing `errors` variable in my old code. It's all good now. thanks